# Element not showing on iOS form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, forms, jquery-validate

**What I'm wanting:**
When a form is submitted show a "Order Processing" element.

**What I did:**

```
$("#register").validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) { },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $('.processing-wrapper').removeClass('hidden');
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

**What I'm experiencing:**

- On the desktop things work as expected -
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7zOsmA6qCA
- On iOS I never see the
  "Order Processing" element -
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5xbYchqJpE

**What I've tried:**

- I commented out the form.submit(); just to see if the "Order Processing" element would show up on iOS, and it did. But when the form is submitted I never see the processing element.
- I tried adding setTimeout to delay the form submission to see if that would allow more time for the "Order Processing" element to show on iOS, but had trouble getting it actually submit the form.

*Updated with timeout*

```
$("#register").validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) { },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $('.processing-wrapper').removeClass('hidden');
    setTimeout(function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }, 2500);
  }
});
```

With this update I do see the "Order Processing" element but also get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined"

**Recap:**

- Any idea why it the "Order Processing" element doesn't show up on iOS?
- Any suggestions on getting the setTimeout to actually work?

*Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout method is the correct fix, however you're getting the error because you've set the anonymous function to accept a `form` parameter which is over-riding the `form` of the outer scope and is null, hence the error. Just remove that parameter and it should work fine:

```
$("#register").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) { },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $('.processing-wrapper').removeClass('hidden');
        setTimeout(function() { // no parameter here
            form.submit();
        }, 50);
    }
});
```

Note that the timer delay can be much shorter, I reduced it to 50ms in my example. All you need to do is ensure that the call to remove the class is made before the submit happens so the UI has a chance to update.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! To clarify is it that iOS cannot remove the class and submit the form at the same time? Does iOS freeze the UI once the submit happens?

Comment: It's not that the UI freezes as such, but just stops responding to any calls to the current page when a request to load a new page is executed.